# Python GPIO write to set GPIO power output failing

Tags: python, openwrt, vocore

I am attempting to control the GPIO pins on a single-board computer (Vocore v2) running Open-Wrt Linux. The script attempts to control the GPIO pins via the file system. However, while the pins export flawlessly, the value (or power) of the pin is never set! Does anyone know why `powerPin()` never sets the power value of the GPIO pin? How can I fix this problem?

Thank you.

My Python script:

```
 '''
This script is an introductory attempt to create a global Python GPIO control program.


The pinAction class requires several variables to be set:
[pin number]
[direction (read or write)]
[output value (if write is set)]
[read value (if read is set; updates on interval flag)]
[read update interval (if read is set, this is an integer value indicating the frequency of which pin values are read)]
'''

#Import all modules necessary for the script...
from subprocess import call
import sys

class pinAction:
    
    def __init__(self,pin,direction):
        #Set object properties...
        self.pin = int(pin)
        #Test direction argument...
        self.direction = "in" if direction == "in" else "out" if direction == "out" else False
        if not self.direction:
            #Incorrect argument: terminate the program...
            print "Error: pin direction must be 'in' or 'out'. Terminating program..."
            sys.exit()
        else:
            call('echo '+self.direction+' > direction',shell=True)
            
        #Initialize the GPIO pin through the file system...
        call("cd /sys/class/gpio && echo "+str(self.pin)+" > export",shell=True)
        print "Successfully initialized pin "+str(self.pin)+"."
        
    def powerPin(self, power):
        if self.direction == "out":
            print "Setting pin power output..."
            power = 0 if int(power) == 0 else 1 if int(power) == 1 else False
            if not power:
                print "Error: power argument must be an integer or string of '0' or '1'."
            else:
                call("echo "+str(power)+" > value && cat value",shell=True)
                #call("ls && echo "+str(power)+" > value",shell=True)
        else:
            print "Error: pin is not an output pin!"
                        
x = pinAction(1,"out")
#Set pin power to be on...
x.powerPin(1)
```

The script outputs the following in the terminal:

> Successfully initialized pin 1.
>
> Setting pin power output...
>
> 1

Comment: Can you provide the output of the script? You have a lot of print messages and since we probably don't have the hardware, this is a tough one to debug

Comment: @AK47 Thanks, I updated to provide print output. I'll try your suggestion regarding the ternary operator....

Comment: @AK47 I updated the ternary but the problem persists :(

Comment: Where is your code to actually set the GPIO power? Is it done by setting the value '1' in the value file?

Comment: @AK47 the "1" in the terminal output is from the `cat value` in the call command. It seems it is being set but when I manually cd into /sys/class/gpio/gpio1 and run `cat value`, it returns 0.

Comment: @AK47 Yes, you are correct, the power is set by setting the value to 1 in the value file.

Comment: @AK47 I uncommented the last line and it appears Python was writing a value file in the working directory of the script. Quite weird. I guess persistence doesn't apply in the terminal or it uses live persistence where user-run terminal commands apply to the same scope of the Python script causing the working directory to change. I'll write an answer once I test everything. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction to isolate the problem!

Comment: I took a guess at the answer. Let me know if it's wrong so I can delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that every time you invoke the `call()` function your current working directory is reset to the directory at which the script lies.

In your `powerPin()` function, update the line:

```
call("echo "+str(power)+" > value && cat value",shell=True)
```

to be

```
call("cd /sys/class/gpio/gpio{0} && echo {1} > value".format(str(self.pin), str(power)))
```

so that the value file is created in the directory `/sys/class/gpio/gpio${x}` :: where `${x}` is the number of the pin